# Ошибка incompatible types при попытке присвоить типу float значение с дробью

Tags: java

Выходит ошибка: `incompatible types` при попытке присвоить типу `float` значение с дробью.

Например:
`float a = 5.12;` - выходит ошибка
`float b = 5.12f;` - ошибки нет

Почему нужно добавлять в конце букву **`f`** чтобы не было ошибок?
Было бы отлично получить ссылку на статью, где это подробно освещается (для новичков).

Comment: потому что по умолчанию double

Comment: а почему например когда я пишу byte a = 1 не выходит ошибка? по умолчанию всё в byte создается?

Comment: `ссыллку на статью где это подробно освещается` - разве ни в одной книге нет?

Comment: `почему например когда я пишу byte a = 1 не выходит ошибка?` - ну ок..... поясняю....по умолчанию для чисел с точечкой - double

Comment: а для целых чисел какой тип по умолчанию берется? byte?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов с целыми числами проще - у них можно проверить минимальное/максимальное значение (например `byte a = 1` отработает, а `byte a = 128` уже не скомпилируется).

Comment: т.е целые числа не обязательно кастить?